# How can i pass function as parameter with arguments

Tags: javascript

I have ajax call function which have parameter function and it's looks like this

```
function selectedLang(func) {

     let selected = selectLang.options[selectLang.selectedIndex].value;

     $.ajax({
          url: 'lang.php',
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { language: selected },
          success: function (data) {
             // call here displayData function with parameter
              func(data);
          }
      });
}
```

inside `success` i want to call function `displayData` with parameter data

```
  function displayData(data) {  
    // some data  
  }

 selectedLang(displayData);
```

Right now i'm getting an error that `func` is not a function

Comment: i will use selectedLang() function to display different data from different functions, so this will not work as i expecting! I need pass function as a parameters

Comment: It should be working fine https://jsfiddle.net/sfu9kt5h/7/

Comment: The problem here might be the ajax call. Try putting the parameter function in a new variable inside selectedLang: `selectedLang(func){ let callback = func; [...] success: callback`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is working.
https://jsfiddle.net/bpomehv5/

Check out this fiddle

```
function selectedLang(func) {

     $.ajax({
          url: 'https://randomuser.me/api',
          type: "GET",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
             // call here displayData function with parameter
              func(data);
          }
      });
}

function showIt (data) {
    console.log(data);
}

selectedLang(showIt);
```

Comment: did you check the fiddle?